# Opening another HTML file through window.open

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button that, once clicked, will open up a local HTML file in a popup window. When I run the code, the button show's up on my page, but when I click on it, nothing happens. Here's the code I have right now:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Positioning a Popup Window in the Center of the Window</title> 
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
function openWindow() {
     var w = 480, h = 340;

     if (document.getElementById) { 
         w = screen.availWidth;
         h = screen.availHeight;
     }

var popW = 300, popH = 200;

var leftPos = (w-popW)/2;
var topPos = (h-popH)/2;

msgWindow = window.open('separateHTML.html','popup','width=' + popW  + ',height=' + popH + ',top=' + topPos + ',left=' + leftPos + ', scrollbars=yes');

</script>
<form>
<input type="button" onClick="openWindow()" value="Click Me"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The URL 'separateHTML.html' refers to another HTML file I have in the same directory as this HTML file. Why won't the button won't go to 'separateHTML.html'?

Comment: What ancient example did you get this from with the getElementById check?

Comment: @علاءالدين And where is node in this?

Comment: lol it's a homework assignment i'm struggling with

Comment: you're forgetting to close brackets at the end of function "}"

Comment: you missing `}` at the end of `openWindow` declaration

Comment: close brackets, otherwise jsfiddle please

Comment: Use your developer console. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: thanks guys. pretty dumb mistake on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to close brackets at the end of function "}"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">PopUp Window</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("separateHTML.html", "_blank", top=300, left=200, width=480, height=340");
}
</script>
```